# Nonstandard evaluation of list of variable names

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, evaluation

I'm writing an estimation procedure in R loops through a list of variables names from a data.frame that the user declares. I'm trying to avoid requiring the user to enquote the variables to make their life easier (the goal is to upload this to CRAN, so we care a lot about user experience).

To prevent R from trying to evaluate the variable names, I constructed the function `alt()` that is like an alternative to `c()` and `list()`, but does not evaluate the elements.

My question is how I can elegantly do away with the `alt()` function, so users can learn one less function. Here is a simple MWE that hopefully illustrates the problem:

```
## Construct non-evaluating list function
alt <- function(...) {
    alt <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))
    return(alt[-1])
}

## Construct function that enquotes non-evaluated vectors
## contained in 'alt()'. Perhaps enquoting variable names 
## is unavoidable because the data set is stored as a 
## data.frame, but at least the user will not have to do it.
restring <- function(vector) {
    vector <- deparse(vector)
    if (substr(vector, start = 1, stop = 2) == "c(") {
        vector <- substr(vector, 3, nchar(vector) - 1)
        vector <- strsplit(vector, ", ")[[1]]
    }
    return(vector)
}

## Example of a function that loops over the list above
## for a given data set. The function simply prints out 
## the columns declared in each element of 'alt()'.
test <- function(data, vlist) {
    for (i in 1:length(vlist)) {
        print(paste0("Data set ", i, ":"))
        print(data[, restring(vlist[[i]])])
    }
}

## Construct example data
N <- 4
df <- data.frame(x1 = c(1, 2),
                 x2 = c(3, 4))

## Example of user-declared list of variables to loop over
vlist <- alt(x1, c(x1, x2))

## Output from running this example
> test(df, vlist)
[1] "Data set 1:"
[1] 1 2
[1] "Data set 2:"
  x1 x2
1  1  3
2  2  4
```

The user could also have declared

```
test(df, alt(x1, c(x1, x2)))
```

But it would be nice if I did not have to require the user to use a different function to declare these lists of variables. If it could work using standard R functions, like

```
test(df, list(x1, c(x1, x2)))
```

that would be great, but I haven't been able to find a way other than performing some ungainly string manipulations using `deparse(substitute())`, similar to the `restring()` function (not sure how CRAN feels about that).

Any thoughts on this non-standard evaluation issue would be appreciated. Also, if `alt()` is easy enough to use that it is not worth removing, that would also be good to know.

Comment: If you want them to be able to use symbols outside the main `test()` function call such as with `vlist <- alt(x1, c(x1, x2))` then you really are going to need to keep `alt()`. You can do some nonstandard evaluation when you call `test()` but that won't help when you actually want to force evaluation. Doing this stuff might seem like a good idea, but when users go to write their own functions that wrap functions like these, things can get very messy. I'm not sure avoiding enquote makes things any easier if they just need to learn a whole new paradigm instead.

Comment: Formulas are another way someone might capture symbols rather than evaluate them. For example `vlist <- list(~x1, ~x1+x2)`

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks so much for the responses. I had not considered using formulas. But what you mentioned about using symbols outside of `test()` is really important, and was something I had not considered. Given that, I think I will indeed have to hold onto the `alt()` function. Again, user experience is something we're concerned about, and it seems that the cost to the user of learning a simple auxiliary function to list variables is worth it if the main function can then be used in more complex settings. Thanks again for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

A more compact option would be `en_exprs` from `rlang`

```
library(rlang)
alt1 <- function(...) enexprs(...)
test(df, alt1(x1, c(x1, x2)))
#[1] "Data set 1:"
#[1] 1 2
#[1] "Data set 2:"
#  x1 x2
#1  1  3
#2  2  4
```

---

Or without using any external package, `quote` the expressions in a `list`

```
test(df, list(quote(x1), quote(c(x1, x2))))
#[1] "Data set 1:"
#[1] 1 2
#[1] "Data set 2:"
#  x1 x2
#1  1  3
#2  2  4
```